# how to specify values on $this->fetch() cakephp 2.1

Tags: php, cakephp, view, controller

We all know that $content_for_layout is now deprecated in cakephp 2.1 and changed to $this->fetch('content');

wherever we put that fetch('content') it is where the contents of the view where the layout is tag will be viewed.

my question is for example I have a view navigation(), the contents of that view will be placed on $this->fetch('nav_view'), and for the view main_board() the contents will be on $this->fetch('main_board'),

and this two fetches will be outputted on the same layout. is it possible??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhere in your view/element/helper:

```
$this->start('nav_view');
// render your 'nav_view' stuff here
echo $this->element('...');
$this->end();
```

Render the same as content:

```
// in layout
$this->fetch('nav_view');
```

Apparently, this is now documented in the cookbook, under [Using view blocks](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#using-view-blocks).

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm such a lazy researcher. haha!